# Euclidean geometry and $L_2(\lambda)$ space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, euclidean-geometry, inner-products

Suppose $f,g\in L_2(I,\lambda)$ with $\lambda$ any probability measure and the norm $\| x\|=\sqrt{\langle x,  x\rangle}$.  Could we have the same geometric properties in this space as in the Euclidean spaces? i.e.

1. if $h$ is the middle point of $f$ and $g$, i.e.  $h=\frac{1}{2}(f+g)$, then  $\| f-h\|=\|h-g\|$.
2. if   $\| x-f\|=\|x-g\|$  and $h$ is the middle point of $f$ and $g$,  then $\langle x-h,  h\rangle=0$?

Comment: Just write out (1) and you will see that it is true. (2) is not true even in $\mathbb{R}^2$ - take $f = (0,1), g = (1,0)$ and $x=(0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks.  Oh..For the second question, I mean $\langle x-h, f-g\rangle=0$, i.e. so we can apply the  existing properties in Euclidean geometry to such a function space?

Comment: Q 2 as corrected by the OP's  comment above, follows directly from $h=(f+g)/2$ and $||x-f||^2=||x-g||^2 $.

Answer (score 0):

The span of two linearly independent vectors in a Hilbert space is isometric to $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb C^2$ (depending on whether you're using real or complex scalars).